# Displaying database table data in Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am trying to get the data from SQLite database and display it in a table format in Android. Here is the code for displaying data:

```
    Cursor c=db.getAllTitles();
    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            DisplayTitle(c);
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
```

And the `DisplayTitle` function looks as shown below:

```
public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)
{   
    txt.setText(c.getString(0));
    txt.setTextColor(Color.blue(1));

    tr.addView(txt);
    tl.addView(tr);
}
```

Here, `txt` is a `TextView` variable that I have globally declared in the class. `tl` is the `TableLayout` variable and `tr` is `TableRow` variable that I have declared globally in the class.

This doesn't work. However, if I use `Toast` function, the data pulled from the database is getting displayed. Please help.

Here is the link to the entire code:

http://pastebin.me/24d7e33ce334e56087dcb657081684e9

Comment: Folks could probably guess what the layout xml looks like, but how about you show yours, just the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that for each data record you need to declare a *new* table row with a new text view.  From the explanation, it doesn't seem that you want to use the same table row and same text view for all data records.

If you're still stuck, please post a more complete code example.  Preferably so complete that others can replicate your problem.  Also, please explain what "This doesnt work" means.

Comment: http://pastebin.me/24d7e33ce334e56087dcb657081684e9 .. Pls view the complete code here.... IT doesnt work means that i get the "Your application stopped working unexpectedly" error message ...

Comment: Did you make the change I suggested?  Are you still having a problem?  Are you able to post the complete code, including the layout XML and the Manifest, as requested?

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
public Cursor getAll()  
{
   return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
   KEY_MOVES, KEY_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

after that use this code in main activity

```
private void getall()  
{

   db.open();

   Cursor c = db.SortAllRows();
   int i=1;
   if (c.moveToFirst())   
   {        
      do
      {
         DisplayContact(c,i++);
      } while (c.moveToNext());
   }
   c.close();
   db.close();
}

public void DisplayContact(Cursor c,int row )   
{            
 String name11 = c.getString(1) + c.getString(2) + c.getString(3);           
 tv1.setText(name11 );
}
```